# How to target a data-ref with a specific value and add a style using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to target a data-ref with a specific value and add an inline style="display:none;" to it.

How can this be achived? Can someone help me please?

This is how it looks:

```html
<div data="{test-bubble}}" data-ref="bubbles[test-link.com/test]" class="bubbles" state="default">
</div>
```

I tried this but it does not work:

```js
var bubbleremoval = document.querySelector('[data-ref="bubbles[test-link.com/test]"]')
bubbleremoval.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: can you explain more, required output

Comment: Works fine here, https://jsfiddle.net/rscL8o19/ - so you will need to give us a proper [mre] of your issue.

Comment: Might be another possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1427878)

Comment: This should work fine though

Comment: After more testing I found out that the problem was coming from something else and not my code. Thank you to everyone for taking the time to respond :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"""Your code should work if you are applying to a single element since query selector returns one element but for several elements you could fetch by classname and loop through the elements and remove display for each"""
var bubbleremoval = document.getElementsByClassName('bubbles')
     for (let i = 0; i < bubbleremoval.length; i++) {
        bubbleremoval[i].style.display = "none";
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I found out that the problem was related to something else and not my code.